# TypeScript Generic Classes: Cannot assign to Generic Type Variable

Tags: generics, typescript, compiler-errors

I'm trying to use Generic interfaces for my classes.
My Class has a generic Type which Extends an interface and a class variable with that Type. But as soon as I try to assign a value to that variable the compiler gives me an error.(Example: Class A)

When I don't extend the Generic Type it works. (Example: Class B)

```
//Generic Classes problem
interface MyStateInterface {
    test?: number
}

class A<IState extends MyStateInterface> {
    protected state: IState;

    constructor() {
        // Error here
        this.state = {
            test: 1
        };
    }
}

class B<IState extends MyStateInterface> {
    protected state: MyStateInterface;

    constructor() {
        this.state = {
            test: 1
        };
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class A<IState extends MyStateInterface> {
    protected state: IState;

    constructor() {
        this.state = { ...
```

What you've said is that `IState` *extends* `MyStateInterface`. This means someone could instantiate `A` with a *more specific type* than `MyStateInterface`. Specifically, someone could add new required properties:

```
interface MyCoolState extends MyStateInterface {
  required: string;
}
let x = new A<MyCoolState>();
```

When this happens, your constructor code breaks the contract of `MyCoolState` by initializing `state` with a value that lacks `required`.

How you fix this depends on what you're trying to do. Usually when people find themselves in this situation, the correct thing is to not be generic at all -- it is *already* legal for subclasses to override `state` with a more-derived type, so if that's the behavior you're trying to enable, you don't need generics at all.